# Java security file location in Android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, jsse, java-security, android-security

In my computer, I can find the java security file under the following path:

```
jre/lib/security/java.security
```

Where does android store this file in Android 4.1 and above ? & Is it only accessible by rooted device?

**==== UPDATE ====**

In general, I need to know where does android maintain the list of security providers(e.g. AndroidOpenSSL, HarmonyJSSE, etc). I guess there should be a system file maintaining the list of those providers(like the file `jre/lib/security/java.security` in my computer).

Where is that file located? I know I can use [Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Security.html) class to get the list, but I need to know the location of the file in Android.

(The reason why I want to know the location of that file in android is that I would like to change the order of the providers.)

Comment: I don't think it exists.  Android doesn't use the jre, and permissions are handled completely differently.

Comment: @GabeSechan , But there must be a file maintain the list of security providers, in my computer it is in `jre/lib/security/java.security`, android must have that kind of file, that is what I am actually asking. But thanks anyhow.

Comment: @GabeSechan, what? do you mean even not maintained in a system file? If you are sure about what you said, could you please give a direction to me, where does android maintain the security providers? At least, I tried the code `Security.getProviders()` it does list all the providers in my Android device, that's why I guessed there must be a system file maintaining the list of security provider.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  There are differences between Java and Android's implementation.  It does provide the java.security namespace (including java.security.Security), but that doesn't mean its implementation is the same-  there doesn't have to be an equivalent to that file

Comment: @GabeSechan, to clarify, I am not saying the implementation in android is the same as that in standard jre. But I am saying there should be a system file in android maintaining the list of security provider, and I am wondering where is the location of that file. Do you happen to know?

Comment: There isn't.  See:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21417  I also see an article about how to add an alternative SSL provider, it requires a rebuild of the framework.  See http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10896?page=0,2

Comment: Basically from what I can tell, its hard coded into the framework and cannot be modified via config file.

Comment: @GabeSechan, the 1st link you provided was posted in 2011-2012 , it is relatively too old to be a good reference. I am not going to register a new provider, I want to change the order of the provider list. I will update my post. I will see if any other opinions coming. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: I supremely doubt its changed.  Basically nobody who isn't an OEM has a usecase for changing the providers.  Why go through the difficulty of making it mutable?  Especially since it would decrease security (by changing that file a malicious actor can do all sorts of interesting things by making themselves default).  What you want doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

> Where does android store this file in Android 4.0 and above ?

Android 6.0 does not use that file, and I doubt that prior versions of Android do either.

> But there must be a file maintain the list of security providers

There must be a list of security providers. This list does not have to be maintained in a text file.

> I tried the code Security.getProviders() it does list all the providers in my Android device

If you read [the source code to `java.security.Security` for Android 6.0.1 r16](http://xref.opersys.com/android-6.0.1_r16/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/security/Security.java), you will see that there are two possible sources of the provider list:

1. [The `security.properties` text](http://xref.opersys.com/android-6.0.0_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/security/security.properties) baked into the libcore JAR as a JAR resource
2. A hard-coded roster in the `Security` source code, if for some reason `security.properties` cannot be loaded

Note that older versions of Android may differ here, and device manufacturers/custom ROM developers may alter this further.

> The reason why I want to know the location of that file in android is that I would like to change the order of the providers

At best, on a rooted device, you could try to hack a replacement `security.properties` into that JAR.

Comment: Thanks, the source code link is very convincing. Old android version is out of the scope of my question, I only concern 4.1+

Comment: @Leem.fin: Well, there were a lot of releases between 4.1 and 6.0. Opersys' [Android Xref](http://xref.opersys.com/) will let you examine other versions of that file, or you can use the git repos, etc.